# CASL. Проблема в проверке прав

Tags: javascript, node.js, авторизация

Для авторизации в приложении используется CASL. 
На этапе авторизации я назначаю пользователю такое право

```
...
can('read', 'timetables', {userId : userId});
...
```

Написал простую обёртку для проверки прав

```
module.exports.checkAuth = async (ability, action, obj) => {
return ability.can(action, obj);
}
```

На клиенте при получении всех timetables я пишу такой код:

```
const result = await checkAuth(req.ability, 'read', 'timetables');
if (!result) throw this.service.errors.unauthorized;
```

Я ожидаю получить выброс исключения, т.к. пользователь имеет право читать не все timetables, а те, которые удовлетворяют ограничению. Однако проверка прав проходит успешно. Подскажите, где ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исключение не выбрасывается по той причине, что когда делается [проверка по имени класса](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/abilities/2017/07/21/check-abilities.html) (в этом случае `timetables`), то это все равно что спросить "Имеет ли пользователь доступ на чтение, хотя бы к одному timetable". И ответ конешно же "true"! Потому что он может читать все `timetables` где `userId` равно его `id`.

Если Вы хотите проверить какой-то конкретный `timetable` его нужно передать вторым аргументом.

```
const timetable = await Timetable.findById(req.params.id)
const result = await checkAuth(req.ability, 'read', timetable);
if (!result) throw this.service.errors.unauthorized;
```

Код для загрузки конкретного `timetable` конечно, же может выглядеть по другому, это зависит от конкретного роута и АРI фреймворка и ORM/ODM. Если же нужно получить все timetable из базы, тогда можно использовать `accessibleBy` метод mongoose модели, [детальнее об этом здесь](https://github.com/stalniy/casl/tree/master/packages/casl-mongoose):

```
const count = await Timetable.accessibleBy(req.ability).count();
if (count === 0) throw this.service.errors.unauthorized;
```

Хотя последний пример не имеет особо смысла. Что Вы хотите так это позволить пользователю читать timetables, если их нет в базе, должен вернутся пустой массив. В противном случае это будет странно возвращать ошибку если в базе нет данных и возвращать массив если кто-то создал `timetables` для пользователя.

Comment: Ваш ответ понятен. Тогда у меня вопрос: как проверить доступ ко всем timetables? Просто в моём приложении обычный пользователь не может читать все timetables, а может читать только те, где userId у timetable совпадает с его. При запросе на получение всех timetables (URL: /api/timetables) пользователь имеет неограниченный доступ к получению всех timetables, но мне надо, чтобы такого не было. В то же время администратор может видеть все timetables

Comment: Если Вы используете http://mongoosejs.com/ то есть дополнительный модуль `@casl/mongoose`, который как раз делает то что Вам нужно https://github.com/stalniy/casl/tree/master/packages/casl-mongoose

Если что-то другое, тогда нужно самому написать прослойку для выборки данных в соответствии с правами доступа. Об этом можно узнать больше в документации: https://stalniy.github.io/casl/abilities/database/integration/2017/07/22/database-integration.html

Comment: Рекомендую также посмотреть эту статью https://medium.com/dailyjs/authorization-with-casl-in-express-app-d94eb2e2b73b и пример интеграции с Expressjs: https://github.com/stalniy/casl-express-example